# Legend div in Google map API

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

This is my first time working with HTML/JavaScript. Trying to add a legend to my Google map API. Can someone tell me what I may be doing wrong
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJP7g.jpg)

Comment: your <div></div> is currently in the <script> </script>, but it should be placed inside the <body> </body>.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Leave the Javascript inside the `script` tags. And html outside of them. Html tags have to be inside the `body`. 
`document.getElementById('id')` reffers to html objects.